# why the input doesn't save my input in txt file in c?

Tags: c

when i input vaccine data, my txt only save this:
ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ   ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ   ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ   -858993460  -107374176.0000 -107374176.000000

so this is my code:

```
 void addvac()
    {
        int option, i;
        struct Vaccine vacc[6];
        printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n\t\t\t Add Vaccine ");
        printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        getchar();
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter Name: "); gets(vacc[i].vaccine);
            printf("Enter Code: "); scanf("%s", vacc[i].code);
            printf("Enter Produce by : "); scanf("%s", vacc[i].produce);
            printf("Enter Dosage : "); scanf("%d", &vacc[i].dosage_taken);
            printf("Enter Population Covered : "); scanf("%f", &vacc[i].population_size);
            printf("Enter Quantity : "); scanf("%f", &vacc[i].quantity);
            getchar();
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        
        
        FILE* fptr;
        fptr = fopen("Vaccine.txt", "w");
    
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].vaccine);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].code);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].produce);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t", vacc[i].dosage_taken);
        fprintf(fptr, "%.4f\t", vacc[i].population_size);
        fprintf(fptr, "%f", vacc[i].quantity);
    
        
        
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

how can i save the input to my txt?

Comment: Think of what is the value of `i` after the loop.

Comment: Never use `gets` or `scanf("%s", ....)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].vaccine);
fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].code);
fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].produce);
fprintf(fptr, "%d\t", vacc[i].dosage_taken);
fprintf(fptr, "%.4f\t", vacc[i].population_size);
fprintf(fptr, "%f", vacc[i].quantity);
```

Wrap above code in for-loop. Now your output code is working with index = 2, which is invalid Vaccine element. You only inputed within index (0, 1).

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].vaccine);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].code);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", vacc[i].produce);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d\t", vacc[i].dosage_taken);
        fprintf(fptr, "%.4f\t", vacc[i].population_size);
        fprintf(fptr, "%f", vacc[i].quantity);
}
```